# W/Choreographer: OPTS_INPUT: First frame was drawed before optimized, so skip

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

So i created a recyclerview and make it as default (vertically) and it work fine, load 8/8 image i put. But the problem is when i change the orientation to (Horizontal) it only load 2/8 image and output an Error/Warning
**W/Choreographer: OPTS_INPUT: First frame was drawed before optimized, so skip!**

In The RecyclerViewAdapter
I used Glide to load the image

```
Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImage.get(position))
                .into(holder.image);
```

In The Fragment

It works on Vertical Orientation

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
```

But when i change the orientation

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
```

it only load 2/8 image

This is the code for Home_Fragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

//Vars
private ArrayList<String> mImage = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mTitle = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> mDesc = new ArrayList<>();

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // initialize container view
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    // pass container view to bitmap images so that will use to initialize recyclerView
    initBitmapImages(view);

    return view;
}



private void initBitmapImages(View view){
    Log.d(TAG, "initBitmapImages: preparing bitmaps");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 1");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 1");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 2");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 2");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 3");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 3");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 4");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 4");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 5");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 5");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 6");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 6");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 7");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 7");

    mImage.add("https://i.redd.it/j6myfqglup501.jpg");
    mTitle.add("Foto 8");
    mDesc.add("This is foto 8");

    initRecyclerView(view);
}
private void initRecyclerView(View view){
    Log.d(TAG, "initRecyclerView: init recyclerView");

    RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mImage,mTitle,mDesc,getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false));
}
```